# How to add add-on repo with ADT 15?

Tags: android, adt

It was easy with early ADT versions but now i can't find this function. This is official info http://developer.android.com/sdk/adding-components.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a repo via `Tools -> Manage Add-on Sites...`, which can be found in the SDK-manager. You can start the manager by using `Window -> Android SDK Manager` from eclipse or by running the `android` application in your `ANDROID_SDK/tools` directory.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot sometimes Mac OS fullscreen mode making problems.