# Unable to find Tools -> Manage Add-on Sites... in Android's Eclipse ADT Bundle

Tags: android, adt, eclipse-adt

As suggested in below link I am unable to find Tools -> Manage Add-on Sites... in Android's Eclipse ADT Bundle. Any help would be appreciated.

[How to add add-on repo with ADT 15?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328449/how-to-add-add-on-repo-with-adt-15)

Comment: Have you updated the SDK ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Bad... Actually tools is not a part of any options present in the pop up. You are able to see it when you check out the main menu on the top left of your desktop. As far as ubuntu is concerned it is not straight forward visible which made me believe that there is some thing wrong with my SDK manager.

Attaching the screenshot for anyone who gets confused by the pop up. Take mouse to top left to find tools there..[image]

Comment: I would say that this is a bad design by Ubuntu. Spent 2 hours to find this.